# add on.exit expr to parent call?

Tags: r

Is it possible to add an on.exit expr to the parent call? If so, how?

For example, say that parentOnExit(expr) is a function implementing this. Then for the following code:

```
f <- function() {
  parentOnExit(print("B"))
  print("A")
}
```

I want to see "A" printed, then "B".

Background: What brought this to mind was the following... we have a collection of functions, some of which call others, which require a resource that should be shared from the topmost call down and which also should be closed upon exiting the topmost function. Eg, a connection to a remote server which is expensive to open. One pattern for this is:

```
foo <- function(r=NULL) {
  if (is.null(r)) {  # If we weren't passed open connection, open one
    r <- openR()
    on.exit(close(r))
  }
  bar(r=r)  # Pass the open connection down
}
```

I was hoping to abstract those three lines down to:

```
r <- openIfNull(r)  # Magically call on.exit(close(r)) in scope of caller
```

Now that I think about it though, perhaps it's worth some repeated code to avoid anything too magical. But still I'm curious about the answer to my original question. Thank you!

Comment: This isn't making sense to me. If the goal is to pass an open connection back from the function, why would you close it with `on.exit`?

Comment: I don't want to call on.exit inside openIfNull. I want to call it in the context of the function calling openIfNull given openIfNull did return a new open connection. So, calling openIfNull would have the side effect of also automatically closing a new connection on exiting the function in which openIfNull was called. (This conversation kind of confirms for me that this is a bad idea though.)

Comment: @DavidF - As DWin answered, your current top example isn't great. Simply defining `parentOnExit <- on.exit` would solve that one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was intrigued by the problem and tried a couple of ways to solve it. Unfortunately, they didn't work. I'm therefore inclined to believe that it can't be done. ...But someone else might be able to prove me wrong!

Anyway, I though I'd post my failed attempts so that they are recorded. I made them so that they would print "ONEXIT!" *after* "Not yet!" if they worked...

1 - First, simply try to evaluate the `on.exit` in the parent environment:

```
f <- function() { eval(on.exit(cat('ONEXIT!\n')), parent.frame()); 42 }
g <- function() { x<-f(); cat('Not yet!\n'); x }
g() # Nope, doesn't work!
```

This doesn't work, probably because the `on.exit` function adds stuff to the current stack frame, not the current environment.

2 - Step up the game and try to return an expression that is evaluated by the caller:

```
f <- function() { quote( {on.exit(cat('ONEXIT!\n')); 42}) }
g <- function() { x<-eval(f()); cat('Not yet!\n'); x }
g() # Nope, doesn't work!
```

This doesn't work either, probably because `eval` has its own stack frame, different from `g`.

3 - Bring my A-game, and try to rely on lazy evaluation:

```
h <- function(x) sys.frame(sys.nframe())
f <- function() { h({cat('Registering\n');on.exit(cat("ONEXIT!\n"));42}) }
g <- function() { x<-f()$x; cat('Not yet!\n'); x }
g() # Worse, "ONEXIT!" is never printed...
```

This one returns an environment to the caller, and when the caller accesses "x" in it, the expression including `on.exit` is evaluated. ...But it seems `on.exit` does not register at all in this case.

4 - Hmm. There is one way that might still work: a `.Call` to some C code that calls `on.exit`. It might be that calling C won't add another stack frame... This is a bit too complex for me to test now, but maybe some RAPI/RCpp guru could give it a shot?

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer -- "no answer" -- unless/until someone produces something that does work. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Have you checked my solution ?

Answer (score 14):

I have seen in this recent mail discussion (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-November/067874.html) that you can use **do.call** for this:

```
f <- function() { do.call("on.exit", list(quote(cat('ONEXIT!\n'))), envir = parent.frame()); 42 }
g <- function() { x <- f(); cat('Not yet!\n'); x }
g()
#Not yet!
#ONEXIT!
#[1] 42
```

Using this feature and an additional ugly trick to pass the R connection object to the caller environment, it seems to solve the problem:

```r
openR <- function(id = "connection1") {
  message('openR():', id)
  list(id)
}

closeR <- function(r) {
  message('closeR():', r[[1]]) 
}

openRIfNull <- function(r) {
  if (length(r)) return(r)
  # create the connection
  r <- openR("openRIfNull")
  # save it in the parent call environment
  parent_env <- parent.frame()
  assign("..openRIfNull_r_connection..", r, envir = parent_env)
  
  do.call("on.exit", list(quote(closeR(..openRIfNull_r_connection..))), envir = parent_env)
  
  r
}

foo <- function(r = NULL) {
  message('entered foo()')
  r <- openRIfNull(r)
  bar(r = r)  # Pass the open connection down
  message('exited foo()')
}

bar <- function(r) {
  message('bar()')
}
```

example use:

```
foo()
# entered foo()
# openR():openRIfNull
# bar()
# exited foo()
# closeR():openRIfNull

foo(openR('before'))
# entered foo()
# openR():before
# bar()
# exited foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

I remain confused, but if Tommy can't do it, I suspect I won't be able to either. This does the first task and since it seemed so simple I thought I must be missing something:

```
 f <- function() {
   on.exit(print("B"))
   print("A")
 }
```

Second effort:

```
  txtB <- textConnection("test b")
  txt <-textConnection("test A")
  f <- function(con) { df <- read.table(con); 
                  if( isOpen(txtB)){ print("B open")
                            eval( close(txtB), env=.GlobalEnv ) }
                  return(df) }
  txtB  #just to make sure it's still open
#     description            class             mode             text 
#    "\"test b\"" "textConnection"              "r"           "text" 
#          opened         can read        can write 
#        "opened"            "yes"             "no" 
  dat <- f(txt); dat
#[1] "B open"
#    V1 V2
#1 test  A
 txtB
 #Error in summary.connection(x) : invalid connection
```

(OK, I edited it to close a connection within the calling environment.)
So what am I missing? (It wasn't clear to me as I tested this that connections actually have environments.)

Comment: The `r <- openIfNull(r)` example shows more clearly what he wants: To call a function that returns something (`r`) *and* adds an `on.exit` expression to clean up `r`...

Comment: I stuck in a second effort. Am I still missing something?

Comment: The question here is whether a function `f2`, called within a function `f1`, can use `on.exit` to record expressions that will be carried out *on exit from function `f1`*.

Comment: @Josh: Is function `f1` going to be "expecting" to get an `on.exit` call or is this supposed to be a "stealth" effect that will get sprung on exit from whatever-is-the-next-function?

Comment: @DWin I'd say the effect on f1 from the call to f2 is supposed to be expected. f1 would need to be aware, for example, that it could not usefully return r (as opposed to passing it on in subcalls). Apologies for the confusing example in the beginning. (I think what I'm asking for might be something one would use a macro for in other languages, eg, Scheme.) Thanks for helping to expose the ambiguities in what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is quite old, there is a simple fix for any future visitors:

Use `add=TRUE`   (I don't find the documentation very clear.)

```
f <- function() {

     on.exit(expr = print("B"),
             add = TRUE)
     print("A")
```

}

A another solution is using [withr::defer()](https://withr.r-lib.org/reference/defer.html) which has more options and better documentation.

The [vignette](https://withr.r-lib.org/articles/changing-and-restoring-state.html) is especially helpful.